# Evaluate only one from a set of procedures

Tags: programming, evaluation

Let's say I've got a list of procedures:

```
{Print[1];, Print[2];, Print[3];}
```

And I want to only evaluate 3rd one:

```
{Print[1];, Print[2];, Print[3];}[[3]]
```

> ```
> 1... 2... 3...
> ```

Well, that's not what I've wanted, the walkaround would be to use `Hold`:

```
Hold[{Print[1];, Print[2];, Print[3];}][[ 1, 3]]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

**My question is:** is there more "proper" way to do this?

p.s. the most tidy what I thought of is `Switch`:

```
Switch[2,
 1, Print[1],
 2, Print[2],
 3, Print[3] ]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Comment: Since `Part` doesn't have attribute HoldAll, you either 1) wrap the commands in `Hold` or `Unevaluated`, 2) redefine `Part`, or 3) add via `UpSet` a new definition to `Part` to handle held input (wrapped in e.g. `hold`) differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new function with attribute `HoldAll`, but I don't think you can avoid using `Unevaluated` or `Hold`.

```
Attributes[holdChoice] = {HoldAll};
holdChoice[cases__, n_] := (Unevaluated@{cases})[[n]];

holdChoice[Print[1]; 11, Print[2]; 22, Print[3]; 33, 2]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[21]:= 2
>
> Out[23]= 22
> ```

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the Attributes. This is the way too. I'm just thinking if I don't miss anything. I mean, I want to avoid reinventing the solution which might be there. `Switch` seems to be ok but there is unecessary `1`, `2`... for each case :) too much work ;P